# how to change the size of the rendering surface in opengl/egl?

Tags: opengl-es, egl

I am working in OpenGL ES 2.0 with C. (Not Android)
I want to change the size of the egl surface so that i can render two different contexts on the screen at the same time.

Is it possible to resize the egl surface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What platform / window system is being used ? The windowsurface comes from the "window" - and hence depends on the windowsystem - for example, if using X, it will come from a client window. If using fullscreen "NULL" windowsystem, the size of the framebuffer. If Qt, a widgetsurface or similar.

Example using a NULL system is below:

https://github.com/prabindh/sgxperf/blob/master/sgxperf_gles20_vg.cpp

To answer - EGL only refers to a window already created, hence cannot resize it by itself. When a client window is resized, EGL then has to update its internals, not the other way round.

You can use glviewport to target different areas of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I resize to a `WxH` surface using EGL/OpenGL

```
   if (surfaceWidth != W || surfaceHeight != H) {
        if (surfaceWidth > 0) {
            eglDestroySurface(eglDpy, eglSurf);
        }
        surfaceWidth = W;
        surfaceHeight = H;
        const EGLint pbufferAttribs[] = {
            EGL_WIDTH, surfaceWidth,
            EGL_HEIGHT, surfaceHeight,
            EGL_NONE,
        };
        eglSurf = eglCreatePbufferSurface(eglDpy, eglCfg, pbufferAttribs);
        eglBindAPI(EGL_OPENGL_API);
        eglCtx = eglCreateContext(eglDpy, eglCfg, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, nullptr);
        eglMakeCurrent(eglDpy, eglSurf, eglSurf, eglCtx);
        ...
   }
```